# Mathematical software for calculating Christoffel symbols, curvatures, etc

Tags: math-software

I'm looking for a Mathematical software that can do the following:

I put in a metric (some kind of a two-dimensional matrix), and the software calculates Christoffel symbols, Ricci curvatures, Paneitz operators, etc.

What software should I use? Can I do this somewhere online? Thanks!

Comment: Did you google a little? What software do you think is not suitable for your needs? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160047

Comment: Any CAS can do that if you write the routine for it.  For example, [this question in mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/)